# Using Gravity Forms "gform_field_validation"

Tags: php, forms, gravity

I want to validate the field using `gform_field_validation` I found [this documentation](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_validation) 
but not that helpful

```
    add_filter("gform_field_validation", "custom_validation", 10, 4);
    function custom_validation($result, $value, $form, $field){
       $number = GFCommon::to_number($value,"");

       if (($field["id"] == 1) && ($field["id"] == 1))
           if( ($result["is_valid"]) && ($number >= 1000) && ($number <= 1999)){
               $result["is_valid"] = false;
               $result["message"] = "INCORRECT NUMBER";
           }
       return $result;
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You can also target a specific field by adding the form id and field id after the hook name.

Comment: @GBD yes, I tried that too but it's not working

Comment: `it's not working` is not enough. Are you getting any error ? what result you get ?

Comment: @GBD the purpose of the code behind is to validate the input before saving the data and display the error message, but unfortunately its accepting any values without validation

Comment: Try to remove `($result["is_valid"])` from `if` and see

Comment: @GBD I tried removing `($result["is_valid"])` and testing the code, but it's not validating the field

Comment: What is value of $number use to check validation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28588/discussion-between-user2079954-and-gbd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GDB Many thanks, here I found the solution as below

```
add_filter("gform_field_validation", "custom_validation", 10, 4);

function custom_validation($result, $value, $form, $field){

   if (($field["id"] == 1) && ($field["id"] == 1))
       if( ((intval($value) > 999) || (intval($value) < 2000)){
           $result["is_valid"] = false;
           $result["message"] = "INCORRECT NUMBER";
       }
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.